# trying to fetch the matching data from the array of objects by comparing array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to compare the array of objects i have which have two values and compare against the same array of objecs whih has more values ut fetch only which are comon in both

not sure how should i do that, I have this arrayofobject with me

```
[{"invoice":"500","number":"2"},{"invoice":"500","number":"1"}]
```

i am trying to match this with same type of arrayofobjects having some more data but the labels for the above is in the other arrayofobjects is this

```
[
    {
        "iNumber": "0312",
        "parentInvcNum": null,
        "billDate": "2023-03-12T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "KING NB",
        "AccountNum": "50078887",
        "status": "L",
    "StatusCode" : "2"
    },
{
        "iNumber": "0332",
        "parentInvcNum": null,
        "billDate": "2023-03-12T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "KING MB",
        "AccountNum": "50073287",
        "status": "K",
    "StatusCode" : "1"
    }
]
```

so trying to figure out that from passed arrayofobjects when compared with the actual arrayofobjects which has more data, it fetches the matching ones and show me that

the match of `invoice` is matching the label of `AccountNum` and the `number` is matching the `statusCode`

i tried explaining above how should i do, i tried the filter and every approach, but i could figure out how can i compare array of arrayofobjects having different labels

Answer (score 1):

If the length of array `A` and array `B` is the same and the elements to be compared are at the same index within those arrays it's pretty easy and a simple for-loop will do.
The elments itself are objects in both arrays, so you can simply use the dot notation to access the objects properties e.g. `arrayA[0].AccountNum` would return the AccountNum of array A's first element.

Here's an example:

```js
let arrayA = [{
    "invoice": "500",
    "number": "2"
}, {
    "invoice": "500",
    "number": "1"
}];

let arrayB = [{
        "iNumber": "0312",
        "parentInvcNum": null,
        "billDate": "2023-03-12T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "KING NB",
        "AccountNum": "50078887",
        "status": "L",
        "StatusCode": "2"
    },
    {
        "iNumber": "0332",
        "parentInvcNum": null,
        "billDate": "2023-03-12T00:00:00Z",
        "billingAddress": "KING MB",
        "AccountNum": "50073287",
        "status": "K",
        "StatusCode": "1"
    }
];

for (let a = 0; a < arrayA.length; a++) {
    console.log(arrayA[a].invoice == arrayB[a].AccountNum, arrayA[a].number == arrayB[a].StatusCode);
}
```